# Fedora - android studio is not running

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, fedora-25

I want to run android studio in fedora 25.
I run `./studio.sh`
and I get this error:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m;support was removed in 8.0
No protocol specified

Start Failed: Internal Error. Failed to initialize graphics environment

java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:115)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:126)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:860)
at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:855)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:854)
at java.awt.Toolkit.getEventQueue(Toolkit.java:1734)
at java.awt.EventQueue.isDispatchThread(EventQueue.java:1043)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread(SwingUtilities.java:1361)
at javax.swing.text.StyleContext.reclaim(StyleContext.java:454)
at javax.swing.text.StyleContext.addAttribute(StyleContext.java:311)
at javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.addAttribute(StyleSheet.java:578)
at javax.swing.text.StyleContext$NamedStyle.addAttribute(StyleContext.java:1501)
at javax.swing.text.StyleContext$NamedStyle.setName(StyleContext.java:1312)
at javax.swing.text.StyleContext$NamedStyle.<init>(StyleContext.java:1259)
at javax.swing.text.StyleContext.addStyle(StyleContext.java:107)
at javax.swing.text.StyleContext.<init>(StyleContext.java:87)
at javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.<init>(StyleSheet.java:166)
at javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit.getStyleSheet(HTMLEditorKit.java:391)
at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.<clinit>(UIUtil.java:98)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.start(PluginManager.java:73)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:39)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:113)
```

any idea how to fix this problem? I tried to unset `Display` or `export Display:=0` and I did not get any solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fedora 25 is not using XOrg anymore by default. We moved to Wayland and Java probably does not handle that. It would be nice to report the problem to Android Studio developers (not here).

Anyway, you can workaround it by running Fedora using old X. Select the "GNOME on XOrg when logging into your account:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I got the below issue because of running as a root user. Once I exit from the root user and tried ./studio.sh it worked perfectly :)

Start Failed: Internal Error. Failed to initialize graphics environment

Answer (score -1):

I got this issue because I was running as root user. This will work fine if you don't change your privilege to the super user